# How to resolve -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x2426ecf0 error

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

HI my app is getting crash with error

-[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x2426ecf0.

Here is the back trace. Please help me how can I found the location of crash.

```
* thread #6: tid = 0x12654, 0x02d84811 CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 769, queue = 'NSOperationQueue 0xb730470, stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x02d84811 CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 769
    frame #1: 0x02d844ee CoreFoundation`_CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    frame #2: 0x02385e97 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_release + 71
    frame #3: 0x02386ce7 libobjc.A.dylib`(anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 537
    frame #4: 0x02d359d8 CoreFoundation`_CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 24
    frame #5: 0x00730b88 Foundation`-[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 958
    frame #6: 0x006ad798 Foundation`-[NSOperation start] + 83
    frame #7: 0x00732d34 Foundation`__NSOQSchedule_f + 62
    frame #8: 0x025ca4b0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 14
    frame #9: 0x025b7034 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 202
    frame #10: 0x025ca4b0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 14
    frame #11: 0x025b8ef1 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_root_queue_drain + 287
    frame #12: 0x025b913d libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_worker_thread2 + 39
    frame #13: 0x02986dab libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 336
```

Comment: Try to use the Zombie instrument (Profile), maybe this help you to find a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may have assigned `autorelease` to instance that's why it is released before you assign value to it.

Find out the `autorelease` of that instance or trace its `release`

i.e.

> cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
>   initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
>   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]  autorelease];
>
> [controller release];